# Finding out if the first digit of every number in an array is odd in C

Tags: c

So basically what my c program needs to do is find out if the first digit of a number is odd, and do so for every element of a 12- element array. Also I need to make the program in the manner that finding out if the first element of a single number is odd needs to be written in a special function outside of main(). This program is really easy to make only in main() but as far as I know you need to use pointers for an array if you want to do something with it outside of main() and I'm not really good at that tbh. So any help would do me a big favour I guess.
This is what I've done so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

```
int function(int p[], int n)
{
    int i;
    int x;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        while (p[i] >= 10)
            ;
        {

            p[i] /= 10;
        }

        if (p[i] % 2 != 0)
        {
            x++;
        }
    }
    return x;
}
```

```
int main()
{
    int n = 12;
    int array[n];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }

    int r;

    r = function(array[n], n);

    printf("%d", r);

    return 0;
}
```

And this is what my apparent errors are:

> ```
> main.c:31:22: warning:        
> passing argument 1 of ‘function’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion] 
> main.c:3:9: note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
> ```

So yeah as I said, any help would do good. Also keep in mind that I'm in the first year of the first semester of college and that we can't really use anything outside of <stdio.h> or <stdlib.h> to write our code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No pointers needed, unless you want to modify the array passed.

---

Some issues:

```
while(p[i] >= 10);{
    p[i] /= 10;
}
```

The above code runs in an infinite loop, after which it runs `p[i] /= 10;` once.

Most C programmers have issues with missing `;`. You have the opposite problem: A `;` where it shouldn't be.

To put it simply, that intruding `;` tells the compiler that the while loop doesn't run any code, so the compiler actually thinks your code means this:

```
while(p[i] >= 10) {
    // Do nothing
}

p[i] /= 10;
```

---

```
int r;

r = function(array[n], n);

printf("%d", r);
```

That r variable is pointless. Unless you don't want to directly pass the return value from `function`

If the value of `n` is 12 then `array[n]` is the 12th element of `array`. Which doesn't exist because `array` only has elements 0-11

This is how I would write the code if I wanted to pass the whole array to my function:

```
printf("%d", function(array, n));
```

---

Here is a working version of the code you want

```
#include <stdio.h>

int count_odd_fdigits();

int main() {
    const int ARRAY_SIZE = 12;

    int array[ARRAY_SIZE];
    int i;

    for (i=0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }
    
    printf("Numbers with an odd first digit: %d", count_odd_fdigits(array, ARRAY_SIZE));

    return(0);
}

int count_odd_fdigits(int numbers[], int limit) {
    int i;
    int count = 0;

    for (i=0; i < limit; ++i) {
        while (numbers[i]/10 > 0)
            numbers[i] /= 10;

        if (numbers[i] % 2 != 0)
            ++count;
    }

    return(count);
}
```

(Run it online: https://onlinegdb.com/yEPr_mYgna)